# How to write a controller method's signature when url has a parameter data after the slash?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-4

In `PHP` there is the possibility to recognize a `parameter` in the address bar by passing it in the controller's method ; for example :

```
http://192.168.2.49/papsp/index.php/meeting/modif/3
```

In this example the data 3 is taken as parameter value for the `meeting` controller's method `modif` :

```
public modif($key) { ... }
```

So how to proceed analogically in Spring ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use the `@RequestMapping` annotation, along with `@PathVariable` with your method param. And your url will be like this `/meeting/modif/{key}`.

Here's how should be your code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/meeting/modif/{key}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void modif(@PathVariable int key) {
```